# SaveAs Method() not working in ASP.Net with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (fileupload1.HasFile)
        {
            String path = Server.MapPath("~\\Voter\\Photos\\");
            Response.Write(path+fileupload1.FileName);
            fileupload1.SaveAs(path + fileupload1.FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            StatusLabel.Text="Unable to Upload";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        StatusLabel.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

The code is neither unable to save the file nor giving any error or exception.

Comment: What does '~\\Voter\\Photos\\' imply? Is it logged in user sensitive? If so check what identity the Web site code is running as.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code to understand which path it is taking through the event handler?

Comment: Its taking the correct path

Comment: Except SaveAs() Every Thing is fine

Comment: What does it say if you do a Directory.Exists(path);

Comment: I created a local application and copied your code into it. If the path doesn't exist I get an exception, if the path does exist the file gets saved. I can't find a combination that doesn't either result in StatusLabel getting set or the file getting saved.

Comment: Try getting rid of the try/catch block and seeing what happens. Also, have you tried debugging?

Comment: Your code is fine. The file gets written but the content is probably not what you're expecting...

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is working properly.
I have Tried your code and it is working correctly.
Here's My Code :

HTML :

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


     <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click1" />


    </form>
</body>
```

Code Behind File :

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                String path = Server.MapPath("~\\Voter\\Photos\\");
                Response.Write(path + FileUpload1.FileName);
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(path + FileUpload1.FileName);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Please Check with This Code.
I hope This will solve your Issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine here too, so If you are viewing the file from Visual studio refresh your destination folder and you should find it; or view it from windows explorer. It may not have the same file extension as you expected.